# Angular 4 i18n for custom attributes

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

Is there a way to translate custom attributes values in child-components using Angular i18n AOT?

I know we can translate HTML element attributes as below.

```
 <input i18n-placeholder="search criteria date @@criteriaDate"
        placeholder="Date"
        formControlName="date" required>
```

But I want to do the same thing for my component attributes. In this example I want to pass title attribute translated value.

```
 <custom-spinner
        formControlName="nights"
        [title]="'Nights'"
        i18n-title="search criteria nights@@criteriaNights">
      </custom-spinner>
```

When I try this, it doesn't generate an entry on messages.xlf file.
I couldn't find any examples on this.

Comment: So, what happens when you do just that? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But this does not generate an entry in messages.xlf file.I will update the question.

Comment: Just use `title="Nights" i18n-title="search criteria nights@@criteriaNights"`. That works fine here. It's useless to use an angular expression and the bracket notation when all you want to pass is a hard-coded string.

Comment: Thank you. It works ! We've used bracket notation unnecessarily.

Comment: Hello i have the same problem with a selfdefined attribute **[errorMsg]** as **@Input()**. This is used in a template of a **@Component** like **<p *ngIf="isInvalid()">{{errorMsg}}</p>**  I think this is not a special case and angular should have a solution for this. Is there a solution too?

Comment: Does the syntax **bind-title="Nights" i18n-bind-title="..."** work? The **bind-title** should be the canonical form of **[title]** .

Answer (score 10):

Tested in Angular 7. It works by default. You can't use [title] notation for i18n texts. It should be plain text.

```
      <custom-spinner
        formControlName="nights"
        title="Nights"
        i18n-title="search criteria nights@@criteriaNights">
      </custom-spinner>
```

Note it will also work for any attributes. For example, `my-attr` and `i18n-my-attr` will translate the text inside `my-attr`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this syntax.
i18n-xxx is basically for compiler to recognize, therefore it doesn't follow Angular template binding syntax

```
<custom-spinner
 formControlName="nights"
 [title]="'Nights'"
 i18n-[title]="search criteria nights@@criteriaNights">
</custom-spinner>
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  With Ivy the string isn't extracted into messages.xlf.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [canonical form](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-target) of angular attribtute binding - it should work with angular 4.4.6 and typescript 2.3.4 too. I have proofed it with this environment:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 6.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

try this solution please - i hope it is helpfull:

```
<custom-spinner
 formControlName="nights"
 bind-title="'Nights'"
 i18n-bind-title="search criteria nights@@criteriaNights">
</custom-spinner>
```